# How to convert file to keystore format

Tags: android, react-native, keytool

I am doing a react-native application.
The issue is, the previous `keystore` is in `.txt` format.
How can I change it into .keystore file?

I already tried these

- changing the file format manually
- using Android studio to re-create the keystore
- using this command
  `keytool -importcert -file ***.keystore.txt -keystore ***.keystore`

I tried to use the original file on the `AppCenter`, but I got
[image]

I tried resaving the file as `.keystore`, but I got

[image]

Is there any other way?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please try with following
"keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore current_keystore.txt -destkeystore new_keystore.keystore -deststoretype pkcs12"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try with following
**"keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore current_keystore.txt -destkeystore new_keystore.keystore -deststoretype pkcs12"**

Comment: Yes. this worked on my end. Thank you.